# I have regex to split string to words, numbers and punctuation marks list. How to make "a-z" and "0-9" single elements of list?

Tags: c#, regex

It's looks so:

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(line, @"\s+|(?!^)(?=\p{P})|(?<=\p{P})(?!$)");
```

It's split `"ASds22d. asd ,156"` to `"ASds22d" + "." + "asd" + "," + "156"`.

Here is problem with strings like "a-z", "0-9" or variations like "a-c" and "4-5". My regex split `"a-z 1-9"` to `"a" + "-" + "z" + "1" + "-" + "9"` but i need just `"a-z" + "1-9"`.

Can someone fix this regex?

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. do you use the punctuation after you've split it up? If not, its probably much easier to just `Split` the string based on a list of punctuation

Comment: Yes, i actually use it. But thank you.

Comment: What about string like `1-c`

Comment: @vks, actually don't mind. This kind of strings is not gonna be here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\s+|(?!^|-)(?=\p{P})|(?<=\p{P})(?<!-)(?!$)
```

You can try something like this.This will not split on `-`.If you have any examples where split on `-` is required it can `OR`ed again.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/3